# How to do a for loop equivalence in JSX?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using picker in React-Native

Now, The [official docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/picker) for picker says something like this

```
<Picker
  selectedValue={this.state.language}
  style={{ height: 50, width: 100 }}
  onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({language: itemValue})}>
  <Picker.Item label="Java" value="java" />
  <Picker.Item label="JavaScript" value="js" />
</Picker>
```

Here I am assuming, the `<Picker.Item label="something" value="something" />` will be things which will be shown in dropdown

Now I have an long array of data which I need to be shown in the drop down or pickup (say Year birth from 1998 to 2018)

**[Question:]** How can I dynamically add label-value in picker.item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing so is by iterating on your array using the `map` function like so

`{youData.map(data => <Picker.Item label={data.label} value={data.value} />}`

In your example, it would be:

```
<Picker
    selectedValue={this.state.language}
    style={{ height: 50, width: 100 }}
    onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({language: itemValue})}>
    {youData.map(data => <Picker.Item label={data.label} value={data.value} />)}
</Picker>
```

Comment: You are missing `(` in the end of map
`{youData.map(data => <Picker.Item label={data.label} value={data.value} />)}`
I would've added but the edit should be greater than 6 characters. also thanks for answering :)

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate the array

```
<Picker
  selectedValue={this.state.language}
  style={{ height: 50, width: 100 }}
  onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({language: itemValue})}>
   {
     Array.map(item => (
       <Picker.Item label={item} value={item} />
      ))
    }
</Picker>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
this.getList =()=>{
   return listData.map((item))=>{
     return <Picker.Item label={item.label} value={item.value} />
   })
}

<Picker
  selectedValue={this.state.language}
  style={{ height: 50, width: 100 }}
  onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({language: itemValue})}>
  {this.getList()}
</Picker>
```

Comment: I swear I though this myself but then felt this won't be quality code. Still thanks a lot :)